# Fastest way to make a fog gradient?

Tags: volumetrics

I need to do a fog that's dense at the bottom and gradually disappears to the top of the box. I adjusted a gradient texture with mapping, but is there a more straighforward way?

Comment: for me that is straight forward ;) i would have done it the same way

Comment: you can also use the Converter > Separate XYZ and its Z output socket

Comment: Does the Z output go from 0 to 1 relative to the bottom and top of the mesh?

Comment: @francoisgibon it does in *generated* texture coordinate.

Answer (score 4):

As moonbots pointed out, you can use *Z* coordinate to get a gradient. You can also raise it to some power for nonlinear falloff (normalized 0..1 range raised to some power is still normalized, which is pleasant), then multiply to change the maximum value:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question has made me curious. I wonder whether there's a way of combining some kind of World Z pass with a Mist pass to approximate this in compositing, without using volumetrics? Somebody must have done this.

Comment: @RobinBetts You can do a worldpos AOC, but there are a number of reasons why a mist pass is not going to give the same results as renderered fog (volumetric lighting, variable density, scattering, many more.)  You can get the integral of a very simple height-based mist pass function, which is even better than volumetric sampling, at least for raw, rasterizer absorption, but it's easy to get mist functions that can only be sampled iteratively; it's possible to sample in composting, but tedious and slow and not what compositing is good at.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan! I think that nails it. My comment should have been a question :)

Comment: How do you change where the volume begins? By default, this starts at the top, I want it to start from the bottom up.

Comment: @no_name you can use *Map Range* node to map from 0..1 to 1..0 for example. Or use a color ramp, or just do Math: subtract: $1-x$.

Comment: I've tried using the math node and the color ramp and neither one changes where the volume starts